# AWS EC - How to run phantomjs server forever

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, phantomjs, amazon-ec2

I have setup phantomjs as web server for scraping on AWS EC. I don't know how to run phantoms script forever through putty? Any alternative for phantom like Forever for NodeJS?

Comment: The same way like every other linux program? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499187/how-to-run-infinitely-script-in-background-on-linux

Comment: I don't think so, people had any luck with nohup and phantomjs. Like 
1: [phantomjs not working with background process nohup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065598/phantomjs-not-working-with-background-process-nohup)
 and 2: [phantomjs with nohup not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479576/phantomjs-with-nohup-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#execute-any-script-what-is-fork-mode) is a good option. You can take a look at the documentation, it enables you to automatically restart your program if it crashes, and has a lot of cool features.

To start your PhantomJS application using PM2, the command would be:

`pm2 start app.js --interpreter phantomjs`

The application will run detached to your SSH session, so you can safely quit your Putty window.

Comment: thanks @christophetd. Sorry, I don't have rights to vote :)